# SSRS Hide data value label in chart legend if the value is 0

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to hide in the Legend the label if the value is 0?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following steps

1. double-click on the chart, right-click the measure you want to hide
   based on parameter value.
2. Click Series properties, go to legend tab.
3. Select the Fx for check box Do notshow this...
4. Add the expression,  according to the parameter flag,
   eg, IIF( Parameters!Flag="T", true, false)
   // If flag = T, then legend will hide and vice-versa

Comment: thanks a lot. This expression was in my Report right: `=iif(Fields!AWM.Value=0, True, False)`

Answer (score 1):

Right click the Legend at the chart then properties. under Visibility tab. Put this expression

```
=IIF(Len(Sum(Fields!FIELD.Value))> 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```